# associative array conundrum in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

In javascript I can 'create' an associative array by initializing a javascript object via JSON

eg var bArr = {"key1": "val1","key2": "val2", "key3": "val3"}

then access the array elements like bArr["key1"], bArr["key2"], bArr["key3"].

However instead of initialization with JSON can we somehow just index elements like bArr["key1"] in a loop and assign them values individually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize values into your javascript object by doing `bArr["key"] = "value";`. Doing this will give you:

```
bArr = {
  "key": "value"
}
```

Thus, using a loop, you can concatenate `i` to the end of your `key` and `value` to generate your object which has keys from 1 to n and values from 1 to n, where n is an integer (of limited size):

```js
var bArr = {};

for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  bArr["key" +i] = "val" + i;
}

console.log(bArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

yes you can. very simple actually:

```js
var obj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  obj['val' + i] = i;
}

console.log(obj);
```